# How to delete undesirable rows in each group based on two conditions?

Tags: pandas

My input is a dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E'],
 'col2': ['x1', 'x2', 'x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x1', 'x2'],
 'col3': ['', 'mssg1', 'mssg2', '', 'mssg3', '', 'mssg4', '', '']})

  col1 col2   col3
0    A   x1       
1    A   x2  mssg1
2    B   x1  mssg2
3    C   x1       
4    D   x1  mssg3
5    D   x2       
6    D   x3  mssg4
7    E   x1       
8    E   x2
```

I need to loop over each group in the column `col1` and see if it's a duplicate and if True, go check the column `col3` and keep only the non empty values. If all values are empty, then keep them all.

For that I made the code below. at first sight, it works but not only it is slow on my real dataset but I also ignore if it misses something in the logic.

```
def clean(x):
    if len(x) > 1 and x['col3'].notna().any():
        return x.loc[x['col3'].notna()]
    else:
        return x

final = df.replace('', None).groupby('col1', as_index=False).apply(clean).droplevel(0).fillna('')
```

My expect output is this :

```
  col1 col2   col3
1    A   x2  mssg1
2    B   x1  mssg2
3    C   x1       
4    D   x1  mssg3
6    D   x3  mssg4
7    E   x1       
8    E   x2
```

Can you guys show me how to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use boolean indexing:

```
# is col3 not empty?
m1 = df['col3'].ne('')
# is m1 not all True per col1?
m2 = ~m1.groupby(df['col1']).transform('any')

out = df[m1|m2]
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2   col3
1    A   x2  mssg1
2    B   x1  mssg2
3    C   x1       
4    D   x1  mssg3
6    D   x3  mssg4
7    E   x1       
8    E   x2
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

If col3 of df is not '', or if all values of col3 in a group when df is grouped by col1 are '', keep it

```
cond1 = df['col3'].eq('')
cond2 = cond1.groupby(df['col1']).transform(all)
out = df[~cond1 | cond2]
```

out:

```
    col1    col2    col3
1   A       x2      mssg1
2   B       x1      mssg2
3   C       x1  
4   D       x1      mssg3
6   D       x3      mssg4
7   E       x1  
8   E       x2
```